# Андроид смартфон как дополнительная вычислительная единица в пк

Tags: android, производительность, процесс, процессор, пк

Можно ли заставить пк думать что мой андроид смартфон это дополнительный процессор/ядра/ что-то в этом роде. Вобщем приобщить его к вычислениям которые делает пк в повседневной работе. Если да, то какие есть варианты?

Comment: Нельзя, архитектура ПК и ОС слишком сложные, что бы такое было возможно

Comment: Почему это нельзя? Есть же всякие облачные вычисления, почему нельзя сделать что то подобное с подключаемым у-вом?

Comment: Потому что на поддержку самой такой возможности уйдёт больше мощностей чем мы сможем поиметь.

Answer (score 1):

В свое время Ритчи и Томпсон написали ОС Plan 9.
В этой ОС пользователь получает доступ к гетерогенной вычислительной среде, в которой физические процессоры могут быть географически разнесены и (возможно) быть на основе разных архитектур.
Вот  когда индустрия перейдет с Windows и Android на Plan 9, тогда можно будет легким движением руки на уровне ОС подключать смартфон к десктопу в качестве еще одного процессора.
Сейчас, конечно, можно написать приблуду, которая для конкретной задачи будет часть вычислений кидать куда-то, возможно и на смартфон.
Но, судя по тому что никто так не делает, игра не стоит свеч.

Answer (score 0):

На прямую сделать можно, но тот, кто может, такие вопросы не задаёт))

Но ещё как вариант, ты можешь построить вычислительную сеть, соеденив ПК и Смартфон.
Но там не повседневные вычисления.

Так же ты можешь сделать телефон сервером для некоторых приложений на ПК, т.о. вычисления будут выполнятся на телефоне, а ПК тока отображать значения. 
К примеру самописный органайзер и т.п. Т.Е. кидать задачи на телефон.

Но соглашусь побольшей части с тем, что написали, игра не стоит свеч.
Другой вопрос - запуск игр на ПК для игры на планшете/смартфоне. Это куда перспективней.